# Pausing a javascript image slider

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have built an image slider with navigation arrows using HTML and javascript. I need a pause button to stop the slideshow as it rotates the image every 5 seconds. Could anyone help me with

```js
<script>

 var index = 1;

 function plusIndex(n){
  index = index + 1;
  showImage(index);
 }

 showImage(1);

 function showImage(n){
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  if(n > x.length){ index = 1};
  if(n < 1){ index = x.length};
  for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
   {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
   }
  x[index-1].style.display = "block";
 }
 autoSlide();
 function autoSlide(){
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
   {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
   }
  if(index > x.length){ index = 1}
  x[index-1].style.display = "block";
  index++;
  setTimeout(autoSlide,5000);
 }

</script>
```

```html
<div id="container_slides">
 <img class="slides"src="IMG EXAMPLE"/>
 <img class="slides"src="IMG EXAMPLE"/>
 <img class="slides"src="IMG EXAMPLE"/>
 <img class="slides"src="IMG EXAMPLE"/>
 <img class="slides"src="IMG EXAMPLE"/>

 <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(-1)" id="btn1">&#10094;</button>
 <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(1)"id="btn2">&#10095;</button>
 
</div>
```

this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Read about [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We need sample code, show us what you did and where you encountered problem.

Comment: Can you check the sample code, it doesn't run. Please correct it if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can pause and unpause with single click. Additional variable to check if slider is in paused state, and if it's set to true, then prevent `setTimeout` execute. And to be sure that image won't change if paused, nice `if` statement at the beginning of function `showImage` and `autoSlide` should help.

```js
var index = 1;
var timeout = null;
var paused = false;

function plusIndex(n) {
  index++;
  showImage(index);
}

function stopSlider(event) {
  paused = !paused;
  event.innerHTML = paused ? "Start" : "Stop";
  paused ? clearTimeout(timeout) : timeout = setTimeout(autoSlide, 5000);
}

showImage(1);

function showImage(n) {
  if (paused) return;
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    index = 1
  };
  if (n < 1) {
    index = x.length
  };
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[index - 1].style.display = "block";
}
autoSlide();

function autoSlide() {
  if (paused) return;
  showImage(index);
  index++;
  timeout = setTimeout(autoSlide, 5000);
}
```

```html
<div id="container_slides">
  <img class="slides" src="IMG EXAMPLE" alt="IMG 1" />
  <img class="slides" src="IMG EXAMPLE" alt="IMG 2" />
  <img class="slides" src="IMG EXAMPLE" alt="IMG 3" />
  <img class="slides" src="IMG EXAMPLE" alt="IMG 4" />
  <img class="slides" src="IMG EXAMPLE" alt="IMG 5" />

  <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(-1)" id="btn1">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="stopSlider(event.target)" id="btn3">Stop</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(1)" id="btn2">&#10095;</button>

</div>
```

Comment: You aren't explaining anything... `:(` But a nice way to pause and unpause! 

Comment: Made edit, I should have put some explanation before.

Comment: Looks good now. 

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `clearTimeout()` for this. So you assign the timer to a global variable (as it needs to be accessible cross function) and then:

```
var a = 0; // Global

a = setTimeout(autoSlide, 5000); // Replace this line.
```

And create a function:

```
function stop() {
  clearTimeout(a);
}
```

Add it to a button:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="stop();">Stop</button>
```

**Full Snippet**

```js
var index = 1;
var a = 0;

function plusIndex(n) {
  index = index + 1;
  showImage(index);
}

showImage(1);

function showImage(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    index = 1
  };
  if (n < 1) {
    index = x.length
  };
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[index - 1].style.display = "block";
}
autoSlide();

function autoSlide() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  if (index > x.length) {
    index = 1
  }
  x[index - 1].style.display = "block";
  index++;
  a = setTimeout(autoSlide, 5000);
}

function stop() {
  clearTimeout(a);
}
```

```html
<div id="container_slides">
  <img class="slides" src="//placehold.it/100?text=1" />
  <img class="slides" src="//placehold.it/100?text=2" />
  <img class="slides" src="//placehold.it/100?text=3" />
  <img class="slides" src="//placehold.it/100?text=4" />
  <img class="slides" src="//placehold.it/100?text=5" />

  <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(-1)" id="btn1">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(1)" id="btn2">&#10095;</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="stop();">Stop</button>
</div>
```

**Demo: http://output.jsbin.com/guyanifogu**